# asp.net core html not updating

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

my html code:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="tiles"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

changed to:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="tiles"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

I made a content div around tiles and list.

My problem is by doing that my html won't update in my browser. 
and yes i already cleared my browser cache, I disabled caching in devtool.
I added no cache meta tag. I rebuild my solution, clean solution no luck. Whatever code i add or delete nothing happens. My css is updated not the html.

I tested it by just deleting my content and when I run my project I still had every content on my browser. What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you create a new view, can you see that in the browser?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your application?

Comment: Try deleting obj folder and bin folder. Then compile and run again

Comment: make sure that you are changing the HTML in the right page. e.g it might be possible that the file you are editing is not exactly the file you need to edit. check the path of the file you are editing , is it the same path of your file that you want to edit.
Go to your project folder , find out that specific aspx page , open it with notepad and see the contents inside.

Comment: i'll check than as for this moment i'm making a new project and copying my code in it. But yes I already tried rebuilding my project and I think i'm sure i'm editing in theright file. the only thing is, I was learning layouts and I created a layout page, but I didn't enabled it and my code refresht before with the layout page so :/

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: @JuliusLimson i think i solved this by resetting browser for chrom its shift+f5 its reset refresh kinda style and  ithink you can use a different browser too to find out it it is browser related. I always have chrome and firefox